# openCV error : undefined reference to `cvLoadImage' Ubuntu

Tags: c++, c, opencv, ubuntu, image-processing

I have installed the openCV libraries but I am still getting the error
**$ g++ -I /usr/include/opencv/ -L -lcxcore -lhighgui hello.cpp -o hello

/tmp/ccjjrbXr.o: In function `main':
hello.cpp:(.text+0x2d): undefined reference to`cvLoadImage'

collect2: ld returned 1 exit status**

When I check for the path of the libraries I get
**$ pkg-config --libs opencv

-lml -lcvaux -lhighgui -lcv -lcxcore**

I have written a very simple program to test it :

```
enter code here

#include< cv.h>  
#include< highgui.h> /* required to use OpenCV's highgui */
#include< stdio.h>

int main() { 
    IplImage* img = 0;
    printf("Hello\n");
    img = cvLoadImage("lena.jpg", 0 );
}
```

There is something wrong with my installation but I am really not able to figure it out. Any guidance will be highly appreciated!
Thanks

---

When I run:

```
$ pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv
-I/usr/local/include/opencv -I/usr/local/include
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_calib3d.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_contrib.so 
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_core.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_features2d.so 
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_flann.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_gpu.so 
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_highgui.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_imgproc.so 
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_legacy.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_ml.so 
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_nonfree.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_objdetect.so 
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_photo.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_stitching.so 
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_ts.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_video.so 
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_videostab.so
```

But when I run:

```
$ g++ 'pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv' display_image.cpp
g++: error: pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv: No such file or directory
```

OpenCV seems to be installed but still the problem persists.

Answer (score 15):

You used single quotes `'` instead of [backquotes/backticks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grave_accent#Use_in_programming) `` ` ``. This is the corrected command:

```
g++ hello.cpp -o hello `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv`
```

Answer (score 0):

It would  be a good idea to link to the highgui lib `-lhighgui` if you are using it

Comment: Sorry, I actually had entered linked all the libs, but made a mistake while entering it the forum. It still gives the same error: 
'**
 g++ -I /usr/include/opencv/ -L -lhighgui hello.cpp -o hello
/tmp/ccw90mKu.o: In function `main':
hello.cpp:(.text+0x2d): undefined reference to `cvLoadImage'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status '**

Comment: @user1111044 - then it probably can't find the lib. Don't you have to specify a directory if you use "-L" ? this might be blocking the standard LD_LIBRARY_PATH search

Comment: Yeah that's the exact problem that I am facing. I do not have a folder to use along with the -L.

Comment: It's probably `/usr/local/lib` but see http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/InstallGuide_Linux

Comment: nah..have tried all these. But thanks a lot Martin for trying to help!

Answer (score 0):

this command:

```
g++ 'pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv' display_image.cpp
```

is different than this:

```
g++ `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv` display_image.cpp
```

because of the ` and ' chars...

if you dont want to mess with those chars, you can use

```
g++ $(pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv) display_image.cpp
```

which is easier to visualize

Answer (score -1):

try g++ -g -o mypro progname.cpp `pkg-config opencv --cflags --libs`
or