# OpenCV undefined reference to

Tags: c++, opencv, clion

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 and OpenCV 2.4.9 and my quite simple example programs are constantly failing to build. I'm building on CLion.

As I'm kinda new to OpenCV I have some issues to narrow down the problem. I tried two different programs.

Number 1 is this one:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    IplImage *img = cvLoadImage(argv[1]);
    cvNamedWindow("Example1", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
    cvShowImage("Example1", img);
    cvWaitKey(0);
    cvReleaseImage(&img);
    cvDestroyWindow("Example1" );
}
```

Which fails with:

```
Scanning dependencies of target untitled
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/untitled.dir/main.cpp.o
[100%] Linking CXX executable untitled
CMakeFiles/untitled.dir/main.cpp.o: In function `main':
/home/computervision/CLionProjects/untitled/main.cpp:7: undefined reference to `cvLoadImage'
/home/computervision/CLionProjects/untitled/main.cpp:8: undefined reference to `cvNamedWindow'
/home/computervision/CLionProjects/untitled/main.cpp:9: undefined reference to `cvShowImage'
/home/computervision/CLionProjects/untitled/main.cpp:10: undefined reference to `cvWaitKey'
/home/computervision/CLionProjects/untitled/main.cpp:11: undefined reference to `cvReleaseImage'
/home/computervision/CLionProjects/untitled/main.cpp:12: undefined reference to `cvDestroyWindow'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
CMakeFiles/untitled.dir/build.make:94: recipe for target 'untitled' failed
make[3]: *** [untitled] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:67: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/untitled.dir/all' failed
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/untitled.dir/all] Error 2
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:79: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/untitled.dir/rule' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/untitled.dir/rule] Error 2
Makefile:118: recipe for target 'untitled' failed
make: *** [untitled] Error 2
```

My 2nd one is this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>

int main( int argc, char** argv ) {

    cv::Mat image;
    image = cv::imread("sample.jpeg" , CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);

    if(! image.data ) {
        std::cout <<  "Could not open or find the image" << std::endl ;
        return -1;
    }

    cv::namedWindow( "Display window", cv::WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
    cv::imshow( "Display window", image );

    cv::waitKey(0);
    return 0;
}
```

Which fails with:

```
Scanning dependencies of target untitled
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/untitled.dir/main.cpp.o
[100%] Linking CXX executable untitled
CMakeFiles/untitled.dir/main.cpp.o: In function `main':
/home/computervision/CLionProjects/untitled/main.cpp:9: undefined reference to `cv::imread(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, int)'
/home/computervision/CLionProjects/untitled/main.cpp:16: undefined reference to `cv::namedWindow(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, int)'
/home/computervision/CLionProjects/untitled/main.cpp:17: undefined reference to `cv::_InputArray::_InputArray(cv::Mat const&)'
/home/computervision/CLionProjects/untitled/main.cpp:17: undefined reference to `cv::imshow(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, cv::_InputArray const&)'
/home/computervision/CLionProjects/untitled/main.cpp:19: undefined reference to `cv::waitKey(int)'
CMakeFiles/untitled.dir/main.cpp.o: In function `cv::Mat::~Mat()':
/usr/local/include/opencv2/core/mat.hpp:278: undefined reference to `cv::fastFree(void*)'
CMakeFiles/untitled.dir/main.cpp.o: In function `cv::Mat::operator=(cv::Mat const&)':
/usr/local/include/opencv2/core/mat.hpp:298: undefined reference to `cv::Mat::copySize(cv::Mat const&)'
CMakeFiles/untitled.dir/main.cpp.o: In function `cv::Mat::release()':
/usr/local/include/opencv2/core/mat.hpp:367: undefined reference to `cv::Mat::deallocate()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
CMakeFiles/untitled.dir/build.make:94: recipe for target 'untitled' failed
make[3]: *** [untitled] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:67: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/untitled.dir/all' failed
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/untitled.dir/all] Error 2
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:79: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/untitled.dir/rule' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/untitled.dir/rule] Error 2
Makefile:118: recipe for target 'untitled' failed
make: *** [untitled] Error 2
```

My CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.9)
project(untitled)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

add_executable(untitled main.cpp)
```

I wonder what I could have done so wrong. 
Most searches lead to wrong settings of the g++ command, but I assume CLion knows what it's doing (also I tried with the command too, same errors).
For instance this here: [openCV error : undefined reference to `cvLoadImage' Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10094692/opencv-error-undefined-reference-to-cvloadimage-ubuntu)

I assume `highgui` is not linked properly. Which might be the case, my output of:

```
computervision@computervision-VirtualBox:~/ex$ pkg-config opencv --libs
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_core.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_flann.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_ml.so
```

looks kinda poor, I assume I made a mistake during installation (just which?).

Another error might be the CMakeLists.txt. [Here](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/issues/2288) it was recommended to change it. But the line

```
LIBRARIES += glog gflags protobuf leveldb snappy
```

causes an error.

Executing

> export CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS=`pkg-config opencv --cflags --libs`

before starting CLion doesn't make any difference either.

EDIT:
Using cmake:

```
computervision@computervision-VirtualBox:~/CLionProjects/untitled$ cmake .
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 5.4.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 5.4.0
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
OpenCV_LIBS: opencv_mlopencv_flannopencv_core
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/computervision/CLionProjects/untitled
computervision@computervision-VirtualBox:~/CLionProjects/untitled$ g++ -o untitled main.cpp `pkg-config opencv --cflags --libs` 
/tmp/ccdAr2hr.o: In function `main':
main.cpp:(.text+0x78): undefined reference to `cv::imread(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, int)'
main.cpp:(.text+0x128): undefined reference to `cv::namedWindow(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, int)'
main.cpp:(.text+0x1a2): undefined reference to `cv::imshow(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, cv::_InputArray const&)'
main.cpp:(.text+0x1ca): undefined reference to `cv::waitKey(int)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

EDIT (2):
Using `make` after `cmake`:

```
computervision@computervision-VirtualBox:~/CLionProjects/untitled$ make 
Scanning dependencies of target untitled
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/untitled.dir/main.cpp.o
[100%] Linking CXX executable untitled
CMakeFiles/untitled.dir/main.cpp.o: In function `main':
main.cpp:(.text+0x78): undefined reference to `cv::imread(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, int)'
main.cpp:(.text+0x128): undefined reference to `cv::namedWindow(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, int)'
main.cpp:(.text+0x1a2): undefined reference to `cv::imshow(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, cv::_InputArray const&)'
main.cpp:(.text+0x1ca): undefined reference to `cv::waitKey(int)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
CMakeFiles/untitled.dir/build.make:97: recipe for target 'untitled' failed
make[2]: *** [untitled] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:67: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/untitled.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/untitled.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:83: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: you are missing the videoio and highgui libraries in the linker args

Comment: Based on your CMakeLists.txt you're not linking with anything at all. Where's the `TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES` command?

Comment: Added both as @nayab suggested. No changes

Comment: Why use v2.4.9 when v3.1+ is available?

Comment: Normally *"out-of-source"* builds are preferred because they don't mix all your build stuff with your source code under version control. So, you would make a subdirectory called `build` underneath the directory containing `CMakeLists.txt` then do `cd build && cmake ..`

Comment: @MarkSetchell - Because I have to use it. Tried that with build. No changes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Linking `OpenCV` in `CMakeLists.txt` is missing.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.9)
project(untitled)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
find_package( OpenCV REQUIRED ) # locate OpenCV in system
include_directories( ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS} ) # provide library headers
add_executable(untitled main.cpp)
target_link_libraries( untitled ${OpenCV_LIBS} /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_highgui.so) # link OpenCV libraries , hightgui.so not found by cmake so this hack
MESSAGE("OpenCV_LIBS: " ${OpenCV_LIBS} )  #display opencv libs found
```

---

if your compiler finds OpenCV and after executing `cmake` it should show OpenCV libraries found.

Comment: No changes. Tried to compile it with CLion and g++.

Comment: did cmake find the OpenCV libraries ?

Comment: I fear I don't quite understand. As said, I'm pretty new to OpenCV

Comment: After executing cmake command , Is it showing the libraries as we have added a message to show the libs found.

Comment: you can see from cmake output, 'OpenCV_LIBS: opencv_ml opencv_flann opencv_core' . It found only ml, flann, core libraries. Your code also need highgui library to compile. after 'cmake .', you have to execute 'make'.

Comment: See update. No changes either. Also tried with `make .` (not documented here)

Comment: I guess problem is with opencv inistallation. Can you search for highgui lib in your system using 'locate libopencv_highgui.so'

Comment: There is no dot after `make`, it is just `make`

Comment: @nayab: `computervision@computervision-VirtualBox:~/CLionProjects/untitled$ locate libopencv_highgui.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_highgui.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_highgui.so.2.4
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_highgui.so.2.4.9`

Comment: I have update cmake with a hack to link highgui  lib directly using the full path. it should work. just do 'cmake .' and 'make'

Comment: @nayab - I did that (see post update). Can it be my installation is faulty?

Comment: as you can see from the output of "pkg-config opencv --cflags --libs", its showing only 3 libraries. I suspect its problem with installation. However after adding highgui lib in CMakeLists.txt, it should work. Can you delete 'CMakeCache.txt' and do "cmake ." and "make"

Comment: Works! Compiles perfect

Comment: Works. Adding **OpenCV REQUIRED** to *find_package*, **${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS}** to *include_directories* and **${OpenCV_LIBS}** to *target_link_libraries* solved my problem. Thank you @nayab.